# Should I use ViewModels and how to handle many-to-many relationships in ViewModels?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm a beginner into .NET so apologies if you find my problem(s) weird. I also checked other Stackoverflow posts about this similar issue that i have, but they didn't really help me grasp this so I decided to ask here directly.

I'm designing an API that I plan to use with Angular later on for a meal ordering and delivery application (similar to HelloFresh and other such services). I follow a very basic Pluralsight course about APIs and .NET and the tutor uses ViewModels for validation. So, my question is, do I really need them and if I do, how do I tackle many-to-many relationships part of the entity? For example, I have this Meal entity which is connected to the entities Ingredient, Category, Size, User (for liking and disliking a Meal), and Bundle all of them in many-to-many fashion. Here is the code from the Meal entity class:

```
    public class Meal {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int SingularPrice { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int Discount { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MealSize> Sizes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MealCategory> Categories { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MealIngredient> Ingredients { get; set; }
        public ICollection<LikedMeals> LikedByUser { get; set; }
        public ICollection<DislikedMeals> DislikedByUser { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MealBundle> Bundles { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is the code from one of the other entities Meal connects to (chose to be the Ingredient one randomly):

```
    public class Ingredient {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Distributor { get; set; }
        public ICollection<IngredientType> Types { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MealIngredient> Meals { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code from their joining entity:

```
    public class MealIngredient {
        public int MealId { get; set; }
        public Meal Meal { get; set; }
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }
        public Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Measurement { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the code from the API that creates a new Meal:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMeal([FromBody] Meal meal){
            if (meal.Ingredients.Count() > 1){
                if (meal.Name != "" && meal.SingularPrice > 0 && meal.Description != ""){
                    await _dbContext.AddAsync(meal);
                    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Created("Successfully created a new meal!",meal);
                }
                else return BadRequest(meal);
            }
            else return BadRequest(meal);
        }
```

Besides telling me what the ViewModel for the Meal entity should look like, I'd also much appreciate if someone does the same for the Ingredient entity as well so I see both sides of the coin, since I plan to implement create methods for the other mentioned entities.

Thanks to anyone who responds to this in advance!

As you can see from the code blocks I posted in the question, I tried to use validation directly in the controller method, but I don't know if I should do that or not.

**EDIT 1** Added a code block as a part of the response to the @Klamsi 's (first) comment.

```
    [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMeal(int id){
            var result = await _dbContext.Meals
                .Include(meal => meal.Categories)
                .Include(meal => meal.Sizes)
                .Include(meal => meal.Ingredients)
                .Include(meal => meal.LikedByUser)
                .Include(meal => meal.DislikedByUser)
                .Include(meal => meal.Bundles)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(meal => meal.Id == id);
            if (result == null) 
                return NotFound();
            else return Ok(result);
        }
```

Comment: I would think the other way. A ViewModel is not something for your model class but your view. Think about: What would a view need to properly display and "manage" a meal.

Comment: I don't even have special model classes, these ViewModels are essentially the model classes the tutor uses in his course. I edited the question above and added a GET call as a response to what I want to show for a meal.

My plan is to only transfer the user related stuff (authentication, who is logged in etc) to the view using Blazor, and then use Observables in the Angular components to get the data i need for the other entities involved. @Klamsi

Comment: Agree with Klamsi: ViewModels are models of your view, not views of your modela. VMs in APIs tend to be inefficient as soon as you do anything other than forms-over-data. I recommend using Data Transfer Objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

Create list of ingedient class and use meal model class as Many to many purpose.

```
public class Meal {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SingularPrice { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Discount { get; set; }
    public List<Ingredient > IngredientData { get; set; }       
}

 public class Ingredient {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Distributor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this one to many relationship? And are these how my model classes should look like?

Comment: As per concept one ViewModel can use multiple models and once you return one view model it have multiple list of which required in your case. kindly study this mechanism and apply accordingly in your assignment. I'm not sure you really need M:M relationship to solve your problem.